# How to access design dialog parameters in sightly html (AEM 6.1)

Tags: aem, sightly

I have defined few parameters in the design dialog of a component. Can somebody please let me know how can i get those parameters in sightly html? In JSP we used to do like below, but how can we do the same thing in the sightly?

```
int startLevel = currentStyle.get("link", 3);
```

Comment: try "${currentStyle.link}"

Comment: it works!! Thanks alot..

Answer (score 2):

The same thing (well, nearly the same) would work in sightly. You can see the objects which are available in every sightly file here: https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-1/develop/sightly/global-objects.html

One of them is the same `currentStyle` object available to JSPs.

```
${currentStyle.link}
```